# Android UI improvement

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an app, I'm almost done but I think the UI is a bit plain, this is how the main menu looks like:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12945652/2012-12-28%2014.25.17.png

Select a method:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12945652/2012-12-28%2014.34.45.png

Settings:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12945652/2012-12-28%2014.34.37.png

Can anyone suggest how I can improve the user interface. I thought about adding 'settings' and 'help' to the action bar but this will make the screen feel more empty with fewer buttons.

Also at the moment, on a tablet the buttons are stretched across the entire screen, is there any UI patterns I should apply for them? I know you know can create a different XML file for higher resolutions but if I move the buttons to one corner there will be a lot of empty space.

At the moment I think the menu looks a bit plain and dull.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it looks too bad. If you are worried about it being too dull you might try playing around with some colors for text, buttons, etc. or background image but you don't want it to be too fancy and overwhelming. I would suggest maybe some type of logo but other than that I don't think its bad

Comment: Ok thanks, I will add a logo. What you suggest to add an action bar for search or leave it as it is?

Comment: Its fine how it is but maybe add an action bar if you need more room or just want to. As for your comment to atreat's post, IMHO you should always plan on more functionality in the future. You may not see a need for anything now but you never know what you will think of in the future or what users may want. It is better to have room and ease of expansion in case you need it down the road. The app I recently inherited, people didn't think was going to get as big as it has but we keep adding to it so I have to re-write to make it more scalable

Comment: Thanks, today I decided to use the PreferenceActivity API to handle the settings rather than just add buttons.

I will try and make a logo too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the tablet, try separating some of your Activities into Fragments and lay them side by side on the bigger screen.

As for your phone UI, I don't think it looked terrible. Sometimes simple and clean can be better. If you're going to continue to add functionality to the app you may want the extra space so you don't have to drastically change the UI to fit a couple of more items in.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about fragments. I will implement this in the future.

About additional functionality, I don't think anything else will be added to the main menu in the future, any features will be consist of user preferences which will be selected from the settings menu.